# The system of Diophantine equations with same solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

There is a system of Diophantine equations:
\begin{equation*} 
 \begin{cases}
   368=x^7 (mod 407)\\
   389=x^{11}(mod 407)
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

However, solving each of them by hand is quite a difficult task. The question is: how knowing both of the equations ease the task? How could they be solved manually in that case?

Comment: Have you tried the Chinese remainder theorem? And your question is unclear to me; do you want to know how to solve the system of equations manually? Or do you want to know how to solve the system manually *given the solutions to each of the individual equations*?

Comment: @Servaes Sorry, I've changed the question - now it should be clear. I want to know how to solve the system manually. Talking about the Chinese remainder theorem, I've thought it's used for linear systems, isn't it?

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(7,11) = 1\,$ so you can get the exponent $1$ on $x$ by a linear combination of $7$ and $11$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.$$\begin{align}
&x^{21}\equiv368^3\equiv103\pmod{407}\implies x^{22}\equiv103x\pmod{407}\\
&x^{22}\equiv389^2\equiv324\pmod{407}\end{align}$$

So we just have to solve $$103x\equiv324\pmod{407}$$

Comment: Thanks! It's completely clear!

Comment: @SilverLight You're welcome.  I should have mentioned that we need to check that the answer is actually a solution to both equations.  The argument above shows only that $15$ is the only possible solution, not that it actually is one.

Answer (score 1):

The Bezout equation  $\gcd(7,11)=\underbrace{\color{#f84}{\bf 1} =\color{#0a0}{11\cdot 2} - \color{#c00}{7\cdot 3}}\,$ yields exponent $\color{#f84}{\bf 1}$ on $\,x\,$ as follows

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ x^{\Large\color{#f84}{\bf 1}}\equiv\, \dfrac{(x^{\Large \color{#0a0}{11}})^{\Large \color{#0a0}2}}{(x^{\Large \color{#c00}{7}})^{\Large \color{#c00}3}}\equiv \dfrac{389^{\large 2}}{368^{\large 3}}\equiv \dfrac{-83}{103}\equiv 15\!\pmod{\!407} $$

i.e. $\ x\equiv -83\cdot 103^{-1}.\,$ The inverse can be computed by the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242).

Notice that our inferences are *unidirectional*, i.e. any solution of the system must satisfy the above. They do not imply that $\,x\equiv 15\,$ is a solution, so you need to check (or prove) that it is.

Comment: but how could i calculate $389^2/368^3$? It's something terrifying

Comment: @SilverLight It boils down to *exactly* the same (omitted) computation as in the other answer. So why did you accept it if you don't know how to finish?

Comment: in the other answer there is a linear Diophantine equation, which i've just solved manually.

Comment: @SilverLight $\, x\equiv b/a\equiv ba^{-1}\iff ax\equiv b\,$ so it is the same linear congruence. I used fractions to make vivid that it is simply the Bezout equation done in the *exponents*.

Comment: I see now, thanks! I'm just not very familiar with all that 
ring theory.

Comment: However, if $ gcd(a,b) \neq 1$, does it change anything?

Comment: @SilverLight $\,a/b := ab^{-1}$ is well-defined $\!\iff\! b^{-1}$ exists $\!\iff b \,$ is coprime to the modulus (by Bezout).  If you are not familiar with modular fractions then simply replace $\,a/b\,$ by $\,ab^{-1}\,$ above. Then we get $\,x\equiv -83(103^{-1})\,$ so $\,103x\equiv -83\equiv 324,\,$ same as the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment; because $407=11\times37$, by the Chinese remainder theorem the system is equivelent to
\begin{eqnarray}
x^7&\equiv&368\equiv5&\pmod{11},\tag{1}\\
x^7&\equiv&368\equiv35&\pmod{37},\tag{2}\\
x^{11}&\equiv&389\equiv4&\pmod{11},\tag{3}\\
x^{11}&\equiv&389\equiv19&\pmod{37}.\tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}
In particular $x\not\equiv0\pmod{11}$ and $x\not\equiv0\pmod{37}$, so by Fermat's little theorem
$$x^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
x^{36}\equiv1\pmod{37}.$$ 
Then congruence $(3)$ immediately shows that $x\equiv4\pmod{11}$, and congruences $(2)$ and $(3)$ together show that $x^{18}\equiv-1\pmod{37}$. Then a bit of fiddling around yields the identity
$$x\equiv x^{37}
\equiv-x^{37+18}
\equiv-x^{11\times 5}
\equiv -19^5\pmod{37},$$
and a quick computation then shows that $x\equiv15\pmod{37}$, so by the Chinese remainder theorem the solution to the system is $x\equiv15\pmod{407}$.